# How to increase Hard-Disk LifeSpan?

Tags: hard-drive, virtual-memory, overwrite

1) What factors affect the life of a hard disk?

2) Does frequent writing on the disk reduce its life?

3) What is the average life span of a hard disk under normal condition?

4) Does less writing and more reading actions taking on the hard disk increase its life?

5) What way the virtual memory ( file paging ) on the disk effect its life ?

6) Is there any particular hard disk especially built for the excessive writing ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google actually did a big study on this. It is available here:

> Eduardo Pinheiro, Wolf-Dietrich Weber and Luiz Andre Barroso
>   [Failure Trends in a Large Disk Drive Population](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/research.google.com/en//archive/disk_failures.pdf)

From this report:

> One of our key ﬁndings has been the lack of a consistent pattern of higher failure rates for higher temperature drives or for those drives at higher utilization levels. Such correlations have been repeatedly highlighted
>   by previous studies, but we are unable to conﬁrm them
>   by observing our population.
>
> […]
>
> Our results conﬁrm the ﬁndings of previous smaller
>   population studies that suggest that some of the SMART
>   parameters are well-correlated with higher failure probabilities. We ﬁnd, for example, that after their ﬁrst scan
>   error, drives are 39 times more likely to fail within 60
>   days than drives with no such errors. First errors in reallocations, ofﬂine reallocations, and probational counts
>   are also strongly correlated to higher failure probabilities.

Biggest thing to do, really, is to keep those drives cool. Heat does a LOT more damage then just reading/writing.

Comment: : While it's a very interesting paper here's a significant quote from the study you reference --> "We conclude that it is unlikely that SMART data (ed: this includes temperature) alone can be effectively used to build models that predict failures of individual drives. "    

In other words its still pretty much a crap-shoot if you've only got a few drives (< 100) you're worried about.  And I wish they'd update it now and then, the biggest drive they studied was 400 GB.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an interesting critique of the Google study:

http://www.quora.com/Hard-Drives/What-are-the-best-things-to-do-to-extend-the-life-of-my-hard-drive

> Comment on linked paper: Saying that temperature and utilization
>   doesn't seem to affect disk life may be misguided; figures 3, 4, and 5
>   tell a more obvious story: ~20% of consumer drives failed in the first
>   year while used in a data center environment. -- Sub-20°C temperatures
>   indicate cold/hot aisle containment (forcing cold air through the
>   server racks), which is typical of data centers. Data center
>   environments tend to be associated with higher utilization; figure 3
>   shows a high correlation between disk utilization and failure rate.

Anyways, his suggestions are this:

> There are a number of things that can extend the life of the disk:
>
> - Maintain a stable temperature that is within the manufacturer's
>     specified range (typically 5-60°C); heating and cooling cycles put
>     stress on the disk
> - Minimize rotation on axes parallel to the disk's platters (wears
>     out    the spindle bearings)
> - Minimize the number of spin-up and spin-down cycles (puts stress on
>     spindle bearings)
> - Avoid shock and vibration that exceeds the manufacturer's
>     specifications
>
> However, my personal philosophy is to hope for he best, plan for the
>   worst, and to not let a $50 component dictate how I use my laptop.
>   Instead, keep important data backed up, expect the disk to die within
>   2 years, replace the disk and battery when they die, and use the
>   machine in the way that makes me feel the most comfortable. --It's a
>   tool, not an investment!